# What does flagging a comment actually do?

Tags: discussion

What happens when a comment is flagged?

Someone posts a comment that adds zero or negative value, I flag the comment.  What happens?

Comment: Related on meta.SE: [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17364/232449)

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes it gets auto-deleted (I think if it receives enough of certain kinds of flags, or if it contains certain words - this mostly relates to getting rid of rude/abusive comments), but normally it just ends up in the moderators' dashboard for us to review.

Unless it's obvious from context that the comment stands alone and should be deleted, I normally visit the post and review the whole thread to check for related comments that become invalid. But it's easier if you do flag all the comments that need attention, not just one.

If I think a comment should be deleted, I'll also check that the flag matches the reason I think it should be deleted, and if it doesn't I might decline the flag first then delete the comment anyway, particularly for the more negative ones like "unfriendly or unkind" or "rude or abusive".

Comment: what difference does the comment deletion reason make? Does it count as a "black mark" against the user's account if it is of a particular type?

Comment: @MD-Tech sort of, the system does alert mods if there are a lot from one user, but it doesn't ever lead to any automatic action.